# Player disappears on Game mode in Uniity 2D while switching scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

I'm making a function that it switches 2 scenes.

When the player enters the trigger, automatically unity switches the scene and in the "Scene view", the player is there, as I wanted. But in the game view, the player dissappears, I don't know why.

I tried to remove a script that it's function is teleport the player to a specific point of the new scene, and it worked.
But obviously I don't want that, because unity automatically teleports the player to a random point, how can I fix that?

Here are the scripts:

TeleportScript:

```
public class EnterScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string transitionName; //Also 1-1
    void Start()
    {
        if (transitionName == PlayerController.sharedInstance.areaTransitionName)
        {
            PlayerController.sharedInstance.transform.position = transform.position; //Moves the player to GameObject position
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

}
```

https://pastebin.com/jdSPhR3s  <-----SceneLoader

https://pastebin.com/KcwHVBfQ <----PlayerController

And a screenshot of my problem:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDCBB.png)

Comment: Are you sure the character isnt under the ground?  Asking because I can see you have some weird z values.

Comment: I would also attempt to change your characters sort order in the sprite renderer to ensure he is always above "the ground" layer of your scene.

Comment: Oh, it was actually that! The carachter was under the ground, I only changed the Z value to 1 and everything was ok, thanks!